# C# the type or namespace Bunifu could not found

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, frameworks, bunifu

When I run C# GUI (Bunifu UI) project in debug mode, project runs fine. When I run the same project in release mode, the compiler shows so many errors, one of them being:

`Error (cs0246) :the type or namespace name 'Bunifu' could not found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

Please help me fast I have very less time to submit my project.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are missing an **assembly reference**? I have the same problem and solved.

In **Solution Explorer**, Right-click **Reference**,

click **Add Reference**, Browse the Bunifu's dll file and add into.

Remove Bunifu (if this exists) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the solution,click clean than rebuild the solution.
or you should use full namespace path like `using solutionName.projectName.yourClassName`

Answer (score 0):

The compiler treats `Bunifu` as a function which is not defined anywhere. This is why you get this error message. You forgot a `uses` clause, linking to the namespaces where `Bunifu` is defined.